# How to remove data from the bellow List when the data has same category so gridview has no repeated category name

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, can someone help me? I need to remove extra from similar categories of `List<device>`. I will use it in a  `GridView.builder` where a category name is displayed. There can also be no category.

```dart
List<Device> _deviceList = [
  Device('id':'d1', 'Name':'Fan', 'Category':'LivingRoom'),
  Device('id':'d2', 'Name':'Tv', 'Category':'LivingRoom'),
  Device('id':'d3', 'Name':'Light', 'Category':''),
  Device('id':'d4', 'Name':'refrigerator', 'Category':'Kitchen'),
];
//I need to filter this so only one livingroom and any other similar category should come only once in GridView
```

[image: I need to remove that extra category that has the same category name. I only want one dinning room]

Comment: Can you put an example of the ouput of your case?

Comment: So you need to filter this list to sublists, where every sublist contains only devices that share the same category id, am I right?

Comment: I need the the above list to have only distinct category that is remove other same categories name and keep one

Comment: If you have multiple categories what should the way to choose the right one be? Take the first one?

Comment: Yes only needed value is the category name the id and name has no use in gridview if categories are giventhe id and name are used when category is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep a `Set` of `category` you already saw while you are filtering:

```dart
class Device {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String category;

  Device(this.id, this.name, this.category);
  
  @override
  String toString() => 'Device($id, $name, $category)';
}

void main() {
  final _deviceList = [
    Device('d1', 'Fan', 'LivingRoom'),
    Device('d2', 'Tv', 'LivingRoom'),
    Device('d3', 'Light', ''),
    Device('d4', 'refrigerator', 'Kitchen'),
    Device('d5', 'Big Light', ''),
    Device('d6', 'Oven', 'Kitchen'),
  ];

  final seenCategories = <String>{};

  final filteredDeviceList = _deviceList.where((device) {
    if (seenCategories.contains(device.category)) return false; // <- If you already saw an item from this category, don't keep it
    seenCategories.add(device.category);  // <- We save the catefory in the set to indicates we already saw a divice from this catefory
    return true;
  });
  
  print(filteredDeviceList);
}
```

It prints:

```
(Device(d1, Fan, LivingRoom), Device(d3, Light, ), Device(d4, refrigerator, Kitchen))
```

Comment: thanks for the help it woks .if you dont mind can you share what is that @override line does

Comment: In dart, each `Object` has a method `String toString();` When you create a `class`, you actually extend the class `Object` and you already have a method `String toString();` which will return (in your case for `Device`) `"Instance of 'Device'"` . And this method `toString()` is the one used by `print` to create a `String` from any `Object`. But I wanted to print the list of devices with their attributes. So I needed to change the already existing method, and that is why I needed to use the `@override` decorator:  To indicates I'm changing an already existing method from the class.

Comment: Here are some information on the `@override` decorator https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/override-constant.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this steps:
first define a class for Device:

```
class Device{
  String id;
  String name;
  String category;
  
  Device(this.id, this.name, this.category);
}
```

then filter the given list as follow:

```
List<Device> _deviceList = [
  Device('d1', 'Fan', 'LivingRoom'),
  Device('d2', 'Tv', 'LivingRoom'),
  Device('d3', 'Light', ''),
  Device('d4', 'refrigerator', 'Kitchen'),
];

String selectedCategory = "LivingRoom";
  
  List<Device> temp = _deviceList.where((element)=>element.category==selectedCategory).toList();
```

---

UPDATE!
for neglecting repetitive elements follow this:

```
List<String> temp = [];
List<Device> result= _deviceList.where((element)=>{
if(temp.contains(element.category)){
return false;
} else {
temp.add(element.category);
return true;
}
}).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you,sorry i asked wrong question but i dont want a list i want to remove the extra categories the idea is delete the extra category so i dont have repetition of categories name in gridview

Comment: Its working but i used other solution i used ur solution and reversed the condition for getting similar list.thanks for the help